# replace digits of a string into others

Tags: python, string, loops

i'm a little stuck with this problem

I have a string with only 1's and 0's
I'm trying to turn every '0' into '10' and every '1' into '01'

I'm not interested in using the replace() function

I've tried this but it only changes '1' into '01',I don't know why '0' is not changed, does anybody know why?  Thanks!

```
mystring='010101'

for i in mystring:
    if(i=='0'):
        i=='01'
    else:
        i='10'
    print(i)
```

Comment: You are iterating string with variable i and replacing same variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Here is the code you are using:

```
mystring='010101'

for i in mystring:
    if(i=='0'):
        i=='01' # This is a comparing operator and this returns false but as you havnt given the variable where it should store the false value. And so I remains unchanged.
    else:
        i='10'
    print(i)
```

## Solution

It is becuase you are using comparing operators instead of assigning operators.

```
mystring = "010101"

for i in mystring:
    if i == "0":
        i = "01" # Use assignment operators instead of comparing operators
    else:
        i = "10"
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `re.sub` with a callback function here:

```
mystring = '010101'
output = re.sub(r'[01]', lambda m: '10' if m.group() == '0' else '01', mystring)
print(output)  # 100110011001
```